# Regular Expression - One Item Has Multiple Words

Tags: c#, regex

I have multiple lines in a text file.

The text file looks similar to this:

Column 1     Column 2             Column 3

12345          stack overflow          12345678

I need a regular expression to check this and then grab column two. My problem is column two can be one or multiple words and I need it to be one item in the string when I grab it or grab other columns.

Comment: What is the delimiter used `\t` or...?

Comment: It's just white space, each item in a column could be a different length.

Comment: Are they aligned using fixed width fonts or are the above in variable width fonts as above? In essence can you define to us in words how to determine if something is in column 2 and then we can help make a regex out of it...

Comment: Everything in column two starts in the same column. For example, Column 1 always starts on column 1 in the text file. Column 2 always starts on column 13 in the text file. Column 3 always starts on column 46.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file line by line and match it using the following regex:

```
^\d*\s*([\w\s]*\w)\s*\d*$
```

Now, the 1st named subgroup should give you what you need. I'm not exactly sure about `C#` syntax, but for notepad++, `$1` works well.

The `^` ensures that the regex starts matching from the very beginning of the read line and the `$` ensures that it matches up till the very end.

The default greedy matching of the regex assures that no extra spaces are captured in the beginning of the column two content and the `\w` at the end ensures no trailing spaces.

If the carriage return and new-line characters are read by your platform as well, you can modify it as:

```
^\s*\d*\s*([\w\s]*\w)\s*\d*\s*$
```